# Reading a dat file in C#

Tags: c#, file

I've tried several ways to open an OTB file (otb files is like dat files), but I can't find out how..
Here's what I tried latest:
http://pastebin.com/vXFN1pmV

Question is: How do you open and read a .dat file in C#? It probably has ASCII characters.
Thanks

Comment: Dat files can contain anything. There is no guarantee it's just ascii

Comment: Your code is doing nothing to read from the file. Where exactly is your problem?

Comment: An OTB file is an image from mobile phones. You'll likely need an SDK / API (or write your own with a specification) - It's uncompressed; so it might be fairly simple to convert to a Bitmap.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/tPJp5.png here's image of whats inside

Comment: You MUST know what is inside that file, how data is organized!! If you don't, foget it. And more: that's not an ASCII file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to read the whole file into a string, you can use [`File.ReadAllText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx). If you want to read a binary file into a `byte[]`, use [`File.ReadAllBytes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx).

Comment: I'm always getting the "System.Bytes[]" output instead of bytes.. Why?

Comment: Here's code: http://pastebin.com/CWV1qhym

Comment: Because that's what you get when you call `ToString()` on `byte[]`. If you want to convert it to some readable string, you need to write that code yourself.

Comment: Try `BitConverter.ToString(bytes);`

Answer (score 0):

OTB file seems (according to [this link](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/otb)) **Nokia Over The Air Bitmap Image**.
Use apps described in that link to open it...

If you want to print out result, try this `BitConverter.ToString(Bytes);`